# Improving Speed of SQL 'Update' function - break into Insert/ Delete?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization, insert-update

I'm running an ETL process and streaming data into a MySQL table.

Now it is being written over a web connection (fairly fast one) -- so that can be a bottleneck.

Anyway, it's a basic insert/ update function. It's a list of IDs as the primary key/ index .... and then a few attributes.

If a new ID is found, insert, otherwise, update ... you get the idea.

Currently doing an "update, else insert" function based on the ID (indexed) is taking 13 rows/ second (which seems pretty abysmal, right?). This is comparing 1000 rows to a database of 250k records, for context.

When doing a "pure" insert everything approach, for comparison, already speeds up the process to 26 rows/ second.

The thing with the pure "insert" approach is that I can have 20 parallel connections "inserting" at once ... (20 is max allowed by web host) ... whereas any "update" function cannot have any parallels running.

Thus 26 x 20 = 520 r/s. Quite greater than 13 r/s, especially if I can rig something up that allows even more data pushed through in parallel.

My question is ... given the massive benefit of inserting vs. updating, is there a way to duplicate the 'update' functionality (I only want the most recent insert of a given ID to survive) .... by doing a massive insert, then running a delete function after the fact, that deletes duplicate IDs that aren't the 'newest' ?

Is this something easy to implement, or something that comes up often?

What else I can do to ensure this update process is faster? I know getting rid of the 'web connection' between the ETL tool and DB is a start, but what else? This seems like it would be a fairly common problem.

Ultimately there are 20 columns, max of probably varchar(50)  ... should I be getting a lot more than 13 rows processed/ second?

Comment: What does your "update, else insert"  code look like currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible 'answers' to your questions.

13/second -- a lot that can be done...

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` ('IODKU') is usually the best way to do "update, else insert" (unless I don't know what you mean by it).

Batched inserts is much faster than inserting one row at a time.  Optimal is around 100 rows giving 10x speedup.  IODKU can (usually) be batched, too; see the `VALUES()` pseudo function.

`BEGIN;`...lots of writes...`COMMIT;` cuts back significantly on the overhead for transaction.

Using a "staging" table for gathering things up update can have a significant benefit.  [My blog discussing that.](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table)  That also covers batch "normalization".

Building Summary Tables on the fly interferes with high speed data ingestion.  [Another blog covers Summary tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).

Normalization can be used for de-dupping, hence shrinking the disk footprint.  This can be important for decreasing I/O for the 'Fact' table in Data Warehousing.  (I am referring to your 20 x `VARCHAR(50)`.)

RAID striping is a hardware help.

Batter-Backed-Write-Cache on a RAID controller makes writes seem instantaneous.

SSDs speed up I/O.

If you provide some more specifics (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`, SQL, etc), I can be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the DBMS, and wrap it in a transaction.

To explain:

1. Load your data into a temporary table in MySQL in the fastest way possible. Bulk load, insert, do whatever works. Look at "load data infile".
2. Outer-join the temporary table to the target table, and INSERT those rows where the PK column of the target table is NULL.
3. Outer-join the temporary table to the target table, and UPDATE those rows where the PK column of the target table is NOT NULL.

Wrap steps 2 and 3 in a begin/commit (or [start transaction]/commit pair for a transaction. The default behaviour is probably autocommit, which will mean you're doing a LOT of database work after every insert/update. Use transactions properly, and the work is only done once for each block.